# Laravel 4 field validation issues on edit

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am using a simple [user auth package](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide). It has default validation on user creation, however, it does not have any sort of user edit functionality. No problem, I can write that in. The problem I am having is on update of the username I am failing validation for the following:

- The email has already been taken.
- The password must be between 4 and 11 characters.
- The password confirmation does not match.

When editing, the email is taken because it's the same email. I'm not evenn editing the password.

So my question: **How do I turn off validation for updating/editing, or better yet, how do I apply different validation rules for those methods?**

Comment: https://github.com/Zizaco/confide#update-an-user ??

Comment: in this case, did you update only the username and save to the current user model(User::find($user_id))? and did you use 'put' on the form method?

Comment: @RobertRozas That was it. $Model->updateUniques() Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing default values, which are provided with package. They can be found on line 50:

```
public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|between:4,11|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'between:4,11',
);
```

In a class ConfideUser.

Just replace those rules with you own. In case you dont have some rules e.g. password_confirmation, then delete it. And also adopt your HTML forms and models/db with new validatiorn rules.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks like the problem was I needed to use $User->updateUniques() instead of $User->save().